# Add minutes to dom countdown timer

Tags: javascript, html, function, time

I made a count down timer but would like to add extra minutes to it with a button.

I made a function to add 1 minute to the timer but i can't get it to add the minute. How would I achieve this?

I commented out the code since it breaks the rest of my code.

The add1Minute() function should add 1 minute to the timer when it isn't running.

I tried doing this by adding 1 to the variable and after that add it to the timer.

```js
let countdown;

    create();

    function create() {

      const mainDiv = document.createElement("div");

      document.body.appendChild(mainDiv);

      const timeDiv = document.createElement("div");

      timeDiv.setAttribute("id", "timeText");

      timeDiv.innerHTML = "25:00";

      mainDiv.appendChild(timeDiv);

      const startButton = document.createElement("button");

      startButton.setAttribute("class", "button");

      //startButton.addEventListener ("id", "startButton");

      startButton.addEventListener("click", startTimer);

      startButton.innerHTML = "start";

      mainDiv.appendChild(startButton);

      const restartButton = document.createElement("button");

      restartButton.setAttribute("class", "button");

      restartButton.addEventListener("click", restartTimer);

      restartButton.innerHTML = "restart";

      mainDiv.appendChild(restartButton);

      /*

      const minute1Button = document.createElement("button");

      minute1Button.setAttribute("class", "button");

      startButton.addEventListener ('click', add1Minute);

      minute1Button.innerHTML = "+ 1 minute";

      mainDiv.appendChild(minute1Button);

      const minute10Button = document.createElement("button");

      minute10Button.setAttribute("class", "button");

      minute10Button.addEventListener ('click',add10Minute);

      minute10Button.innerHTML = "+ 10 minutes";

      mainDiv.appendChild(minute10Button);

      */

    }

    //startTimer()

    function startTimer(sMin1) {

      let sMin = 0.15;

      function add1Minute(sMin) {

        sMin + 1;

        return sMin;

      }

      //if(sMin1 != null){

      //sMin + sMin1;

      //}

      let time = sMin * 60;

      countdown = setInterval(update, 1000);

      function update() {

        let min = Math.floor(time / 60);

        let sec = time % 60;

        sec = sec < 10 ? "0" + sec : sec;

        timeText.innerHTML = min + ":" + sec;

        time--;

        min == 0 && sec == 0 ? clearInterval(countdown) : countdown;

      }

    }

    //function add1Minute(sMin){

    // sMin + 1;

    // return sMin1;

    //}

    function add10Minute() {}

    function restartTimer() {

      clearInterval(countdown);

      document.body.innerHTML = "";

      create();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
let sMin = 0.15;

function add1Minute() {
  if (!countdown) {
    sMin += 1;
  }
}

function startTimer() {
  let time = sMin * 60;

  countdown = setInterval(update, 1000);

  function update() {
    let min = Math.floor(time / 60);
    let sec = time % 60;
    sec = sec < 10 ? "0" + sec : sec;
    timeText.innerHTML = min + ":" + sec;
    time--;
    min == 0 && sec == 0 ? clearInterval(countdown) : countdown;
  }
}
```